# Setting a Custom Image for a Back Button on UINavigationBar shifts to the right

Tags: xcode, back-button, swift4

i am trying to add an image to the back button in navigation controller.  I have been somehow successful. but as . you can see there is a major problem as to the location of the new image.

Shifting back button
[image: Figure 1]

here is my code`

```
let BackImage = UIImage(named: "back_btn")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
BackImage?.stretchableImage(withLeftCapWidth: 30, topCapHeight: 30);
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = BackImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = BackImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "nil"`
```